# insert values in ConcurrentDictionary

Tags: c#-4.0

I'm trying to insert values into ConcurrentDictionary, I'm used to dictionary, so this is does not work:

```
  public ConcurrentDictionary<string, Tuple<double, bool,double>> KeyWords =  new
                ConcurrentDictionary<string, Tuple<double, bool,double>>
    {
        {"Lake", 0.5, false, 1}
    };
```

What is the correct way, hence I'm doing this into class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Collection initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) are syntactic sugar for calls to a public `Add()` method ... which `ConcurrentDictionary` doesn't provide - it has an [`AddOrUpdate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378675.aspx) method instead.

An alternative you can use is an intermediate `Dictionary<>` passed to the constructor overload that accepts an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<K,V>>`:

```
public ConcurrentDictionary<string, Tuple<double, bool,double>> KeyWords =  
    new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Tuple<double, bool,double>>( 
       new Dictionary<string,Tuple<double,bool,double>>
       {
          {"Lake", Tuple.Create(0.5, false, 1.0)},
       } 
    );
```

Note: I corrected your example to use `Tuple.Create()` since tuples are not infered from initializers.

Comment: Thanks, i think I will add the ConcurrentDictionary values in the class constructor. Would you agree with that approach?

Comment: That is also a reasonable alternative.

Answer (score 10):

You can use [dictionary initializer](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2015/04/c-sharp-dictionary-initializers.aspx):

```
var dict = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, string>
    {
        [0] = "zero",
        [1] = "one",
    };
```

Yes I know the question is [c#4](/questions/tagged/c%234)

Comment: This will even work with other types if KEY is different like a string. Ex: `["Lake"] = Tuple.Create(0.5,  false, 1.0),`